# Adding net changes function to existing cdc tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, cdc

I have an existing table in the DB that was created with  the parameter @supports_net_changes set to 0. Hence there is only one function for that table i.e. to get all changes fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_.

How do I now enable the get_net_changes function over it? Do I have to drop existing cdc and the re-create? Haven't been able to get conclusive help on this

Answer (score 0):

I have understood the error. When disabling the existing cdc on table the table name of the captureinstance needed to be properly specified. This was causing the failure and hence I was unable to get the net changes implemented.